# Blending Performance in Skia

Tags: android, performance, vector-graphics, blending, skia

I am developing a vector drawing app for Android and using Skia to render the vector paths. I have an illustrator kind of setup where there can be some predefined number of layers with different blending method for each. I have an internal library which generates vector paths for each of these layers and I am using Skia Canvas to draw each of these paths into different canvases and use a global canvas into which all these individual canvases are blitted. I am seeing some serious performance issues when blending is applied at each layer. I have researched in the internet for possible bottlenecks but could not find any. Any help on where to look for will be appreciated?

Comment: `"and I am using Skia Canvas"` so you are doing low level c/c++ native stuff or what?

Comment: Yes. I am sing native stuff to draw paths